# play video from rtsp link +iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to play video in my application. For this I have used following code:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.boxmusiq.com/ThiruvasakamVideo        /VTS_01_2_converted.mp4"];

moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)]; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
[moviePlayerController play]; 


 Now above url is a http link but I want to play video from rtsp link.
```

My rtsp link is:

> rtsp://v8.cache3.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQlxYJvp0_b1wxMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYIiCgqTg6_XeTww=/0/0/0/video.3gp

If someone has any idea that how to play video from rtsp link. Please provide me some solution.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the following project on [github](https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone) where RTSP was implemented,